# After using filter_out for column in web2py can not get original value

Tags: web2py

I have a problem by getting an original value from mysql database after applying filter_out to the db column using DAL.

For example, I have a table with integer column. Then I filter out it like this:

```
db.mytable.mycolumn.filter_out = lambda mycolumn: "some complex stuff"
                                 if mycolumn is None else "another complex stuff"
```

But how can I retrieve an original value?

```
rows = db().select(db.mytable.mycolumn)  // get filtered data, not the original
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

1. Since the only difference between filtered & unfiltered data is unfiltered had None's, can't you just recognize "some stuff" as coming from None?  (If "some stuff" isn't a distinct constant, or at least recognizable as coming from the filter, I could see that being a problem, but you haven't detailed what "some stuff" is.)
2. If you don't want the table to always be filtered, you shouldn't keep the filter on the table.  If you replace the filter (either set to None or an identity lambda), that should eliminate the filtering, but for every select after that, until you change it again.

Comment: 1. "some stuff" - complex stuff and not a distinct constant. Yes I can parse it anyway I think, but I'm looking for an easier way. 2.yes it's a good point , maybe I'll come to it